# Regarding the 3D model displaying issue of .3ds file in min3D android project

Tags: android

I have display issue when I open 3d   **.3ds** file through min3D android open source project.
The following given below is the approach and step involved before issue raised.
(1) I have developed the my own 3D modeling and save it as monster_high1.3ds

(2) Min3D project successfully able to parse and create the object , I am confirmed for this output

(3) But 3d model isn't displaying at the same XYZ coordinates which I have looked through 3D Max design tools after rendering. That is there is different rendering in context to coordinates by autodesk 3D Max tools and min3D project.

(4) However when I used the .3ds file shipped with the project it is displaying properly .

(5) From the code this issue shouldn’t be comes which is mention below 
Public void initScene()
{
 //Source code
 scene.camera().target = monster.position() ;
}

Which set the camera to current parse object position?
(6) Is there is any way to map the same look from render point of view between any 3D design tools ( like Autodesk 3D Max , render ) to min3d Google open source project .

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the solution , we also need to parse the camera information from 3ds file and then set the camera target to current render model

Comment: i used this link http://min3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ for padsing 3d file, but its not working
can you pls gime your latest code for parsing 3d oblect?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the mapping. It loads correct but once rebuilding, the texture dissapears. Verry annoying and disabling the reload event of different scenes during runtime.

About the camera position, the XYZ of min3d is the same as the XYZ in 3dsMax. So you must place the center of your object, in 3ds max, on coordinates 0, 0, 0. That way you will get a perfect camera position on your scene. (Also, take the same general dimensions for each 3D Object)